# Cartesian Equation of a Plane

Tags: vectors, parametric

Find Cartesian equations for $II_1$:
$\left(\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}3\\-3\\-1\\\end{matrix}\right)+\mu_1\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-1\\1\\\end{matrix}\right)+\mu_2\left(\begin{matrix}2\\0\\-1\\\end{matrix}\right)$

My working out:

In order to find the cartesian equations for $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ , we first extract the equations from the plane, such that for $II_1$:

$x_1=3+\mu_1+2\mu_2\ldots\left(1\right)$

$x_2=-3\ -\ \mu_1\ldots\left(2\right)$

$x_3=-1+\mu_1\ -\ \mu_2\ldots\left(3\right).$

We then add equation $(1)$ and equation $(2)$ simultaneous equations:

$x_1=3+\mu_1+2\mu_2$

$+\ x_2=-3\ -\ \mu_1$

$x_1+x_2=2\mu_2$

$\mu_2=\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}\ldots\left(4\right).$

We can now rearrange equation $(3)$ to make $\mu_2\ $ the subject:

$\mu_2=-1+\mu_1\ -\ x_3.$

Hence, using equation $(4)$, we can deduce that:

$\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}=-1+\mu_1\ -\ x_3,$

which can then be rearranged to make the subject $\mu_1$:

$\mu_1=\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}+1+\ x_3...\ (5).$

Thus, substituting equation $(4)$ and equation $(5)$ into equation $(3)$ gives:

$x_3=-1+\left(\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}+1+\ x_3\right)-\left(\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}\right).$

The answer I got was just $0$... Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: Are those $\mu$'s all supposed to be the same as $\lambda$'s?

Comment: And what is "$II_1$" supposed to be, just the name of the system of equations?

Comment: SORRY ALL!!! I just edited the question I realised I put the wrong matrix in

Comment: yes. $II_1$ is just the name of the system of equations! @RobertTheTutor

Comment: I edited the question, $\lambda$ wasnt suppose to be there @RobertTheTutor

Answer (score 1):

Since you already used $(3)$ to get the value of $\mu_1$, substituting the parameters back in $(3)$ will give you a not so useful true statement, i.e. $0=0$.

Instead, you should use the unused equation $(2)$ :

$$\mu_1 =-3-x_2 =\frac{x_1}{2} +\frac{x_2}{2} +1+x_3 $$ Simplifying this will give you the cartesian equation.

Comment: Ohmy, I feel stupid haha. Thank you!

Comment: @Mon No problem.